# Составить программу,содержащую информацию о заявках на авиабилеты

Tags: c++, структуры, структуры-данных, односвязный-список, динамические-структуры

Помогите пожалуйста пофиксить ошибку или сделать программу с нуля.
Условия задачи на скрине.
А ошибка такая:мне надо в этой программе сделать так,чтобы если я удалю в итоге все билеты,то выведет,что билететов нет при просмотре.А щас там конфуз-ошибка,не может удалится билет,который ты самый первый вводишь,а все остальные удаляются исправно,помогите пофиксить этот код или можете накидать свой.[image: Условия задачи]
Один из вариантов решения проблемы,надо отказаться от идеи создания первого билета в начале программы. Изначально односвязный список должен указывать на NULL. И лишь когда пользователь запросит создание билета - следует это сделать.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;

struct Tickets
{
    char place[25];
    char secondname[25];
    int num;
    float date;
    Tickets *next;
};

Tickets* First();
void AddT(Tickets** pend);
void CoutT(Tickets* fT);
void FindT(Tickets* fT);
void RemoveT(Tickets* fT);

bool prog_rum = true;

int main()
{
    Tickets* FirstT = First();
    Tickets* pend = FirstT;
    system("cls");
    while (prog_rum)
    {
        cout << "Add ticket - enter a\nShow all tickets - enter c\nFind ticket - enter f\nRemove ticket - enter r\nExit - enter e\n";
        char inputChar = tolower(_getch());
        switch (inputChar)
        {
            case 'a':
            {
                system("cls");
                AddT(&pend);
            }
            break;

            case 'c':
            {
                system("cls");
                CoutT(FirstT);
            }
            break;

            case 'f':
            {
                system("cls");
                FindT(FirstT);
            }
            break;

            case 'r':
            {
                system("cls");
                Tickets* uk = FirstT;
                RemoveT(FirstT);

            }
            break;

            case 'e': prog_rum = false;
                break;
        }
        system("cls");
    }
    return 0;
}

Tickets* First()
{
    Tickets* t = new Tickets;
    cout << "Create First ticket\n\nPlace, Surname, Num, Date" << endl;
    cin >> t->place >> t->secondname >> t->num >> t->date;
    t->next = 0;
    return t;
}

void AddT(Tickets** pend)
{
    Tickets* t = new Tickets;
    cout << "Place, Surname, Num, Date" << endl;
    cin >> t->place >> t->secondname >> t->num >> t->date;
    t->next = 0;
    (*pend)->next = t;
    *pend = t;
}

void CoutT(Tickets* fT)
{
    Tickets* t = fT;
    cout << "Place\t\tSurname\t\tNum\t\tDate" << endl;
    while (t)
    {
        cout << t->place << "\t\t" << t->secondname << "\t\t" << t->num << "\t\t" << t->date << endl;
        t = t->next;
    }
    cout <<  "\nPress any button to continue!";
    _getch();
}

void FindT(Tickets* fT)
{
    int n = 0;
    float d = 0;
    cout << "Number and Date" << endl;
    cin >> n >> d;
    Tickets* t = fT;
    cout << "Place\t\tSurname\t\tNum\t\tDate" << endl;
    while (t)
    {
        if (t->date == d && t->num == n)
        {
            cout << t->place << "\t\t" << t->secondname << "\t\t" << t->num << "\t\t" << t->date << endl;
            t = t->next;
        }
        else t = t->next;
    }
    cout << "\nPress any button to continue!";
    _getch();
}

void RemoveT(Tickets* fT)
{
    Tickets* t = fT;
    int n = 0;
    cout << "Number of tickets" << endl;
    cin >> n;
        while (t)
        {
            if (t->next == NULL)
                return;
            else if (t->next->num == n)
            {
                t->next = t->next->next;
            }
            else
            t = t->next;
        }
}
```

Comment: new в явном виде в C++ уже не принято использовать лет 15) используйте контейнеры или умные указатели. Зачем вы рожаете велосипед если уже есть std::list -https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list. У него есть все нужные Вам методы)

Comment: @Maggot потому что какая разница, если результат нужен для экзамена) Преподу до одного места, какие там конвенции))

Answer (score -1):

1. память освобождать не забываем:
2. по вопросу:

   void RemoveT(Tickets* fT)
   {
     ...........
           while (t)
           {
               if (t->next == NULL)
                   return;
               else if (t->next->num == n)
               {
                   Tickets* ptr=t->next;
                   t->next = t->next->next;
                   delete ptr;
                   return;
               }
               else
               t = t->next;
           }
   }

   int main(int argc, char *argv[])
   {
       Tickets* FirstT = First();
       Tickets* tail = new Tickets();
       tail->num=-1;
       tail->next = FirstT;
       Tickets* pend = FirstT;
   .....
    switch (inputChar)
           {
               case 'a':
               {
                   system("cls");
                   AddT(&pend);
               }
               break;

   ```
           case 'c':
           {
               system("cls");
               coutT(tail->next);
           }
           break;

           case 'f':
           {
               system("cls");
               FindT(tail->next);
           }
           break;

           case 'r':
           {
               system("cls");
               Tickets* uk = FirstT;
               RemoveT(tail);

           }
           break;

           case 'e': prog_rum = false;
               break;
       }
   ```

Answer (score -2):

Добавьте один фиктивный элемент списка, который потом пропускать при поиске/выводе 
У вас первый элемент если я понят FirstT.

```
Tickets* tail = new Tickets();
tail->next = FirstT;
```

А ваши вызовы:
CoutT, FindT делать начиная с tail

Comment: Не помогает,либо я что-то не так делаю) Не могли бы сами внести изменения?